# Drag and Drop canvas in HTML5

Tags: html

How to create a drag and drop canvas in HTML 5 ? (something inside the canvas) and how to capture the dropped location ?

Comment: do you want to drag and drop the canvas element itself or something inside the canvas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://html5.litten.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-on-an-html5-canvas/) might be able to give you some pointers on the drag and drop functionality.