# using javascript to drag and drop images on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I tried following the tutorial suggested in answer to the question at [Drag and Drop canvas in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468940/drag-and-drop-canvas-in-html5) but when I load my page in Firefox, the Firebug console displays an error saying that "canvas is null".

The file it's complaining about is the JS file where I've put the code for user interaction:

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var x = 75;
var y = 50;
var WIDTH = 400;
var HEIGHT = 300;
var dragok = false;

function rect(x,y,w,h) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fill();
}

function clear() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function draw() {
 clear();
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
 rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
 rect(x - 15, y - 15, 30, 30);
}

function myMove(e){
 if (dragok){
  x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
 }
}

function myDown(e){
 if (e.pageX < x + 15 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageX > x - 15 +
 canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageY < y + 15 + canvas.offsetTop &&
 e.pageY > y -15 + canvas.offsetTop){
  x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
  dragok = true;
  canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
 }
}

function myUp(){
 dragok = false;
 canvas.onmousemove = null; 
}

init();
canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
```

The main error is "canvas is null", and when I expand that, it complains about `init()` on line 22, `interaction.js()` on line 57. 
Line 22 is the line:

```
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

and line 57 is the line:

```
init();
```

Could someone point out to me where I'm going wrong?

Cheers.

The HTML where my canvas is is this:

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:1px solid">
    Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
```

Comment: Could you share the HTML where your canvas is? Might be a problem with the id, I think maybe the `canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");` is not being recognised. Please confirm your id is correct.

Comment: I tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/agryson/wfxeH/ and it works fine provided the id is correct.

Comment: I've added the HTML where my canvas is.

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the update, should work, see @prageeth 's answer to try something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when your `init()` method is called the `canvas` is not rendered.
Use

```
window.onload = function() {
  init();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've changed that part of the code to: `window.onload = function(){
 init();
}
canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
canvas.onmouseup = myUp;`

and I'm not getting an error because of the lines `canvas.onmousedown = myDown;` and
`canvas.onmouseup = myUp;`

Where should I put these lines? The error says that canvas is undefined, so I assume it's because they should be in a function, but I'm not sure which one?

Comment: Put the lines `canvas.onmousedown = myDown; canvas.onmouseup = myUp;` inside the above `window.onload = function() {}` block

Comment: Great, cheers. That's got rid of the errors I was having, but that code has not added any drag and drop functionality to the images I've drawn on the canvas- is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/agryson/wfxeH/
I'm pretty sure that you've maybe made an error in the id of your canvas.
Make sure your HTML has:

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my HTML already had that for the Canvas ID

Comment: I know, I posted this answer before you posted your HTML snippet (see my last comment on your question), but glad @prageeth's answer was able to help. :)